# How to install the tikzscale package?

Tags: packages, installing, tikzscale

I downloaded [`tikzscale.zip` from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzscale).
I extracted the following files from `tikzscale.zip`:

```
3Dplot.tikz
README
histogramNormal.tikz        
linewidth.tikz
pgfplots-test.tikz
pgfplots.randn.dat
test-tikzscale.pdf
test-tikzscale.tex
testNode.tikz  
testRectangle.tikz  
testgraphic2D.tikz  
tikzscale.dtx
tikzscale.ins
tikzscale.pdf
```

I put all the above files in the same file folder as my main tex file: `main.tex`. The minimal working environment of `main.tex` is as follows.

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathrsfs,bm,graphicx,color,cite,subfigure}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\begin{document}

....

\end{document}
```

But I always got the following error message:

```
Latex Error: File `tikzscale.sty' not found.
```

I am really confused why this happens?

Does anybody know how to isntall this package properly?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by " run latex on tikzscale.ins to get tikzscale.sty"? How to do this?

Comment: pdflatex works. I can compile tikzscale.ins by pdflatex. Just one more question. How to install the package using package manager (since this is a better way)?

Comment: Thank you for your kind and consistent help. I am using MikTex. The link you posted helps me a lot. My problem is completely solved!

Answer (score 4):

You have to compile the `tikzscale.ins` file by `pdflatex`. To do this, open the file in your tex editor and press the button it provides to compile. This compilation will produce `tikzscale.sty` file which you may put in the same directory as the main tex file. Or better put it in your localtexmf folder (refer [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/11232)) to make it available globally.

But the better method is to use your package manager (as you use miktex). Refer to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/11232) for details.